# Create CRUD in Kay Framework: URL not found

Tags: google-app-engine, django-generic-views

I follow this tutorial http://kay-docs.shehas.net/generic_views.html

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# myapp.models

from google.appengine.ext import db

# Create your models here.

class MyModel(db.Model):
  comment = db.StringProperty()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.comment
```

**forms.py**

```
from kay.utils.forms.modelform import ModelForm

from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

**urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# myapp.urls

from kay.generics import crud

from myapp.forms import MyForm
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyCRUDViewGroup(crud.CRUDViewGroup):
  model = MyModel
  form = MyForm

view_groups = [MyCRUDViewGroup()]
```

When I go to localhost:8084/mymodel/list I got

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server.
>
> If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try
>   again.

Is there any suggestion what is wrong here?

UPDATE 1
**app.yaml**

```
application: xxxx
version: 4
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon

- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: kay.main.application
  login: admin
- url: /media
  static_dir: media

- url: /packages
  static_dir: packages

- url: /_generated_media
  static_dir: _generated_media

- url: /_media
  static_dir: kay/media

- url: /_kay/.*
  script: kay.main.application
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: kay.main.application
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/test.*
  script: kay.ext.testutils.gaeunit.application
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: kay.main.application
builtins:
- remote_api: on
- appstats: on
- deferred: on
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

skip_files: |
  ^(.*/)?(
  (_backup/.*)|
  (app\.yaml)|
  (app\.yml)|
  (index\.yaml)|
  (index\.yml)|
  (#.*#)|
  (.*~)|
  (.*\.py[co])|
  (.*\.po)|
  (.*\.pot)|
  (\..*)|
  (app\.yaml\.sample)|
  (index\.yaml\.sample)|
  (cron\.yaml\.sample)|
  (manage\.py)|
  (TODO)|
  (TODO\.pdf)|
  (README)|
  (README\.pdf)|
  (LICENSE)|
  (gaema-LICENSE)|
  (kay\/docs\/.*)|
  (kay\/management\/.*)|
  (kay\/lib\/babel\/localedata\/.*)|
  )$
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be in your app.yaml file.  That file is where all routes start.

Comment: i added app.yaml file, could you please have a look?